# Shell script: Find entries in access log with 500 response within a specified date period

Tags: shell-scripting

Can someone help me with a shell script to figure out the number of 500 HTTP response entries in an access log within a time frame specified?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `awk` to filter in specified time range:

```
# awk '$9 == "500" && $4 <= to && $4 >= from { print $0 }' from="[02/Aug/2011:14:30:00 +0700]" to="[02/Aug/2011:14:32:00 +0700]" /path/to/your/access_log | wc -l
```

The status code and timestamp fields may have different order. Also change `from` and `to` to corresponding format which you are using.

Comment: Thanks @quanta. This seems to work if the dates are in the same month, but not when the dates go beyond 1 month. for e.g. `ls acc* | while read line; do awk '$9 == "500" && $4 <= to && $4 >= from { print $0 }' from="[31/July/2011:00:00:00]" to="[02/August/2011:00:00:00]" "${line}" | wc -l ; done` is 0 for me.

Answer (score 2):

OK. You can convert to Epoch time to compare:

```
#!/bin/bash

from=$(date -d "$(echo "$1" | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "[/:]"; } { print $1" "$2" "$3" "$4":"$5":"$6 }')" +%s)
to=$(date -d "$(echo "$2" | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "[/:]"; } { print $1" "$2" "$3" "$4":"$5":"$6 }')" +%s)

while read line
do
    date=$(echo $line | awk '{ print substr($4, 2, length($4)-1) }' | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "[/:]"; } { print $1" "$2" "$3" "$4":"$5":"$6 }')
    date=$(date -d "$date" +%s)
    [[ $date -ge $from && $date -le $to ]] && echo $line
done < $3
```

and call it with something like this:

```
./log_filtering.sh 30/Jul/2011:15:55:44 02/Aug/2011:01:00:00 access_log
```

I'm trying to write in one-line.

---

Doing with `awk`:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

function toEpoch(t, a) {
    split(t, a, "[/:]")
    split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec", monthname, " ")
    for (i=1; i<=12; i++) month[monthname[i]] = i
    a[2] = month[a[2]]
    return(mktime(a[3]" "a[2]" "a[1]" "a[4]" "a[5]" "a[6]))
}

BEGIN {
    start = toEpoch(starttime)
    end = toEpoch(endtime)
}

{ date = toEpoch(substr($4, 2, length($4)-1)) }
( date >= start ) && ( date <= end )
```

and passing the arguments with `-v`:

```
gawk -f log_filtering.awk -v starttime=30/Jul/2011:04:12:24 -v endtime=02/Aug/2011:04:12:27 access_log
```

Comment: I've edited my post to append an `awk` script.