# How to send an "Everything is OK" notification from Nagios?

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I need to configure Nagios to send a notification that says everything goes well, if there's no problems.

Does this sort of setting exist or is there a plugin for that?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is it that you want it this way (rather than ok messages when state changes from not ok) ? - sounds like extra messages for no gain.

Answer (score 4):

I use the following setup to send an email once per day. This let's me know that all is well with my Nagios server, the email system and the Nagios config.

```
  # nagios/objects/localhost.cfg
  ....
  # Send a message once per day to make sure nagios is working ok
  define service{
        use                     local-service
        host_name               localhost
        service_description     Nagios is OK
        check_command           check_all_is_well
        check_period            morning     ; this is a custom period
        normal_check_interval   60          
            ; setting this to an hour and making the check_period 
            ; interval 59 minutes long each day ensures it only 
            ; happens once per day in a specific window
        }
```

and in you timeperiods config file:

```
# nagios/objects/timeperiods.cfg
....
define timeperiod{
        timeperiod_name morning
        alias           First thing in the am
        monday          06:00-6:59
        tuesday         06:00-6:59
        wednesday       06:00-6:59
        thursday        06:00-6:59
        friday          06:00-6:59
        saturday        06:00-6:59
        sunday          06:00-6:59
        }
```

And the check_all_is_ok command is a simple wrapper around sendmail:

```
# check_all_is_ok
#!/bin/bash

echo "All is well from Nagio on `hostname`" \
       | /etc/nagios/sendmail -s "Nagios on PIP is OK" <your email address>

echo "OK: nagios is ok on `hostname`";
exit 0
```

It doesn't check that there haven't been problems in the prior 24 hours, but you could add some grep-ping of the logs as guanta suggested if you need that. You could also accomplish the once a day requirement by setting normal_check_interval to 1440 (24 hours), but I want the check to be run in a specific window each day.

Answer (score 1):

If you configured daily log rotation (`log_rotation_method=d`), you can write a script to count the number of alerts in `nagios.log`, something like this:

```
[ `grep -c ALERT var/nagios.log` -eq 0 ] && echo "Everything is OK!" | mail -s "Nagios daily report" your@email
```

Put it into a cron job to run at the end of day, before you go to bed.

If you don't, refer to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/296555/shell-script-find-entries-in-access-log-with-500-response-within-a-specified-dat/297021) topic to filter according to the date.

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of others:
I just went through this question myself and the most simple solution came up to the mind is this, checking nagios process every 8 hrs to make sure nagios is running

```
#crontab -e
```

Add the following

`* */8 * * * /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nagios -t 20 -e 5 -F /usr/local/nagios/var/status.dat -C /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios > /var/local/nagios_stats && sendemail -f "NAGIOS STATUS SenderAddress@gmail.com" -u Nagios Process Status -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -xu SenderAddress@gmail.com -xp SenderPassword -o tls=yes -t RecipientAddress@gmail.com -m < /var/local/nagios_stats`

Don't forget to

Creating file in `/var/local/nagios_stats` (or somewhere else but change it in the crontab)

SenderAddress,RecipientAddress,MailPassword

Answer (score 0):

The solution heavily depends on when you actually want to send out notifications:

- On each successful run of an active check: Then it might make sense to actually run the notification step as part of your active check. A simple way would be to wrap your check inside a script that first does the check, introspects the result and sends the notification. You could do that using [embedded Perl](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/embeddedperl.html).
- When things used to be not okay but are now: This is standard behavior.
- On passive checks: This is actually an interesting problem for which I don't have a solution on top of my head...

Depending on the scenario you should decide for one solution. And always remember: do the simplest thing that could possibly work.

Comment: The idea was to send a notification once a day, if there were no problems during last 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late, but for anyone else looking for a solution, there's an easy way using the [livestatus broker module](http://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk_livestatus.html).

Set up livestatus to use a unix socket (Shinken, by default, has it only set up with tcp port, you can add the socket like in the config on [this page](http://www.shinken-monitoring.org/wiki/the_broker_modules)), and you can poll that directly using eg a python script.