# Nagios notification of host back up after being down

Tags: service, host, nagios

Is it possible to get Nagios to send out a single "Host/Service Back Up" notification after a host/service has been down?

For certain notifications, my boss gets notified. Instead of waiting for another host down notification or parsing through the interval of host down emails we were wondering if once the host/service is back up we can get notified a single time.

Any ideas? I have googled and read through manuals to exhaustion and am coming up empty.

At the most basic level, I have thought about picking apart [How to send an "Everything is OK" notification from Nagios?](https://serverfault.com/questions/297293/how-to-send-an-everything-is-ok-notification-from-nagios) but wanted to understand the problem a little more before taking the time to do something which may already exist.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you have "r" (notify on host/service recoveries (UP/OK states)) in your host/service_notification_options?

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I am looking for. I had mixed up terminology and was not aware of recovery notifications. Thanks. If you want to make your comment in to an answer I will gladly accept it. Thanks

Comment: Reading this was confusing -- aren't recovery emails on by default in all the example configurations?

Comment: @KyleSmith They were not for me, no. Ubuntu 12.04, Nagios built from source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converted to an answer:

I'm not sure what you mean. Do you have "r" (notify on host/service recoveries (UP/OK states)) in your host/service_notification_options.