# extract information from a log file

Tags: unix, bash, shell

I wrote a bash script to extract a few Items like the IP addresses that makes the most number of connection attempts, now I want to limit all of this within a time range , lets say the last 5 days/hours.

Example of what I wrote :

-G: Which IP address makes the most number of connection attempts?

```
if [ "$3" = "-G" ]; then 
 I won't write the whole code ! 
echo "IP address makes the most number of connection attempts: \n"
awk '{print $1}' $4 | sort | uniq -c | sort -r -n | awk '{print $2 "\t" $1}' >> Connections 
cat Connections | head -$2 
 rm Connections
```

now I want to add this Items

-O: Limit it to last number of hours

-P: Limit it to the last number of days

and I run it like this : sh -O -P -G *.log

example log file:

```
213.46.27.204 - - [15/Sep/2011:22:55:21 +0100]
213.46.27.204 - - [16/Sep/2011:22:55:21 +0100]
213.46.27.204 - - [17/Sep/2011:22:55:21 +0100]
213.46.27.204 - - [18/Sep/2011:22:55:21 +0100]
213.46.27.204 - - [19/Sep/2011:22:55:21 +0100]
```

please answer just with bash script not python or perl

---

we have the last date in the log file and we want to extract the last 5 hour/day so :

I find this scrip that converted the date to unix recognizable format but since I have Mac OSX I could not run it :( do know why ? )

```
#!/bin/env bash

  temp_date=`cat ./serverlog.log | tail -n1 \
  | cut -d [ -f 2 | cut -d ] -f 1`

  echo "$temp_date"

  temp_date2=`echo $temp_date | \
  sed -e 's/Jan/01/g' \
  -e 's/Feb/02/g' -e 's/Mar/03/g' \
  -e 's/Apr/04/g' -e 's/May/05/g' \
  -e 's/Jun/06/g' -e 's/Jul/07/g' \
  -e 's/Aug/08/g' -e 's/Sep/09/g' \
  -e 's/Oct/10/g' -e 's/Nov/11/g' \
  -e 's/Dec/12/g'`

  echo "$temp_date2"

  temp_year=`echo $temp_date2 | gawk '{print substr($0,7,4)}'`
  temp_month=`echo $temp_date2 | gawk '{print substr($0,4,2)}'`
  temp_day=`echo $temp_date2 | gawk '{print substr($0,1,2)}'`
  temp_time=`echo $temp_date2 | gawk '{print substr($0,12,8)}'`

  #UTC format
  utc_date="$temp_year-$temp_month-$temp_day $temp_time"

  echo "$utc_date"

  reference_seconds=`date --utc -d "$utc_date" +%s`

  echo "$reference_seconds"
```

I recognized that the last step would be to subtract 5 hours/days from the last date

lastdate(converted) - (5*3600) = X, now we can extract the last 5 hours from log file . 
last date - ( 5 *24*3600 ) + X, now we can extract the last 5 days from the log file .

now any idea how to exactly write this?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/296555/shell-script-find-entries-in-access-log-with-500-response-within-a-specified-dat

Comment: it was not what i wanted , I want the Items witihn the last X hours/days !

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  how I miss the "question must show a basic understanding of the problem being discussed" close reason...

Answer (score 0):

There's a script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827930/how-can-i-use-bash-grep-sed-etc-to-grab-a-section-of-a-logfile-between-2-timest) that will output the lines within a certain date range. Pipe the output to your program and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

> it was not what i wanted , I want the Items within the last X
>   hours/days

1. Get the last time with:

   ```
   endtime=`tail -1 $3 | awk '{ print substr($4, 2, length($4)-1) }'`
   ```
2. Convert it to Epoch time.
3. `starttime` is calculated by subtracting the last hours (days) you
   want to filter from the `endtime`:

   ```
   if [ $1 = "-O" ]; then 
       time=`expr $2 \* 60 \* 60`
   fi
   if [ $1 = "-P" ]; then 
       time=`expr $2 \*24 \* 60 \* 60`
   fi

   starttime=`expr endtime.epoch - time`
   ```

Refer to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/296555/shell-script-find-entries-in-access-log-with-500-response-within-a-specified-dat) topic which I mentioned above to complete your task.

Comment: I wrote the script like this :  (for extracting the last 5 hours)                            time=`expr 60 \* 60 \* 24 \* 5`,                             EDATE=`tail -1 final`,                                        SDATE=`expr EDATE - time`                                              but it does not work , expr: non-numeric argument
any idea what should I write ?

Comment: It doesn't work because you didn't convert `EDATE` to Epoch time. And it seems you also lack of the backstick, use `$()` instead.

Comment: now I have time=$(expr 60 \* 60 \* 24 \* 5) which is 432000
and  EDATE=2002-09-26 02:20:30                                                       I wrote SDATE=`expr EDATE - time` it did not run                   expr: non-numeric argument ( how it could subtract that number from a date ?) shouldn't I use command date --date instead ? if so please tell me how

Comment: Convert it to Epoch time with `date +%s`. Didn't you read the above referenced topic?

Comment: now I convert it 1041425721
but still  SDATE=`expr EDATE - time` does not work

Comment: `SDATE=$(expr EDATE - time)`. You should read the document about the basic shell scripting first.