# How to grep httpd error_log within a time range?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, log-files, grep

How can I grep only lines from a huge (120GB) httpd `error_log` based on a time range, say:

```
from 2011-11-15 11:30 pm
to   2011-11-16 01:30 am
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/296555/shell-script-find-entries-in-access-log-with-500-response-within-a-specified-da

Comment: Why didn't you use logrotate?

Comment: it's already rotated. too bad one of the apps generates tons of errors within a day and needed to be extracted for examination ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll probably have to do some drill down, I'd start by getting the date range:

```
grep -e "2011\-11\-[15-16] " error_log > filtered
grep -v -e "2011\-11\-15 [0-10]:" | grep -v -e "2011\-11\-15 11:[0-29]" > filtered
grep -v -e "2011\-11\-16 [2-23]:" | grep -v -e "2011\-11\-16 01:[31-59]" > filtered

cat filtered
```

The most efficient way I can think of but haven't done is to find the start and end bytes of your date range and get that; (which is apparently possible with grep) but I dont know how to get a range of bytes from a file - probably takes some awk skills

Edit: Since this was an interesting question - I did some more digging:

You can get the first byte offset by doing:

```
 # Get first byte offset, leftmost number is the offset...
grep -m 1 -b "2011-11-15 11:3" error_log
 # Get last byte offset
grep -m 1 -b "2011-11-16 01:3" error_log

 #(Subtract first number from last number to get byte length) Then do:

dd if=error_log of=filtered bs=c skip=<first number> count=<last_byte#-first_byte#>
```

Answer (score 1):

awk '$3>"11:30:00" && $3<"13:30:00"' log_file | less

where $3 is the 3rd column of your logfile which is the timestamp, you can use any number as per your logfile.

Comment: You should really read the older answers including the one that was accepted as it is much more thorough than the one you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody wants to get the logs within the particular time rage, maybe you want to get the logs within 5 min you can do like the below

For dynamic time range (eg you dont know the time range but needs logs between last 5 min)

```
#!/bin/bash
LOG_FILE="./modsec.txt"
SEARCH_WORD="ModSecurity: Access denied"
START_TIME=$(date -d "5 minutes ago" "+%H:%M")
END_TIME=$(date "+%H:%M")

# using sed
sed -n "/"$START_TIME"/,/"$CURRENT_TIME"/p" "$LOG_FILE" | grep -w "$SEARCH_WORD"
```

For static time range (you know the time range)

`sed -n "/hh:mm/,/hh:mm/p" "$LOG_FILE" | grep -w "$SEARCH_WORD"`   (you can replace the time range based on your timestamp)