# Split large sql file by location of string OR start sql from last fail

Tags: linux, mysql, sql, vim

I have a 15GB sql file which is a backup of a database. The problem I have is that half way through it, it failed. Luckily, I know which table to pick up from.

Is there a way I can split this SQL file by the starting point of the table I need to pick up from or perhaps get mysql to do this itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sed` to split the file using ranges

```
sed -n '/Start Text/,/End Text/p' >part.sql
```

This will start printing when `/Start Text/` is found and will continue printing until `/End Text/` or end of file is reached. Make sure `Start Text` is unique to the starting point and `End Text` isn't in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split` command (look into the line count option), 
or you can use `dd` with a byte offset (found using `grep -b`) to extract from your dumpfile as well.

[Here's a blog post](http://tales.itnobody.com/2011/11/grepping-extremely-large-files.html) that covers that process (this is an answer I [gave elsewhere on the site](https://serverfault.com/questions/331372/how-to-grep-httpd-error-log-within-a-time-range/331378#331378) and decided to blog the solution).